# Strange -0f inside XmlConvert.ToSingle

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core

It is code from .net: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/XmlConvert.cs#L1035

```
public static Single ToSingle (string s) {
        s = TrimString(s);
        if(s == "-INF") return Single.NegativeInfinity;
        if(s == "INF") return Single.PositiveInfinity;
        float f =  Single.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign|NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint|NumberStyles.AllowExponent, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        if (f == 0 && s[0] == '-') {
            return -0f;
        }
        return f;
}
```

I cannot understand what happens here...
Let's say comparing of float with 0.0 is OK since it is zero and all bits are zero. So in theory it should be equal to 0.0f; So binary representation of zero should be the same.

But what is about -0.0f? What is purpose of such code?

> > -0.0f
>   0
>
> > (-0.0f).ToString()
>   "0"
>
> > -0.0f == 0.0f
>   true
>
> > (-0.0f).ToString("+0;-#")
>   "+0"
>
> > (-1.0f).ToString("+0;-#")
>   "-1"

Comment: I don't know the impact, but `0.0f` and `-0.0f` don't have the same binary representation: http://ideone.com/0UDBJl

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) wiki article answers this question.

> Signed zero is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic,
>   the number 0 does not have a sign, so that −0, +0 and 0 are identical.
>   However, in computing, some number representations allow for the
>   existence of two zeros, often denoted by −0 (negative zero) and +0
>   (positive zero), regarded as equal by the numerical comparison
>   operations but with possible different behaviors in particular
>   operations. This occurs in the sign and magnitude and ones' complement
>   signed number representations for integers, and in most floating-point
>   number representations. The number 0 is usually encoded as +0, but can
>   be represented by either +0 or −0.
>
> The IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic (presently used by
>   most computers and programming languages that support floating point
>   numbers) requires both +0 and −0. Real arithmetic with signed zeros
>   can be considered a variant of the extended real number line such that
>   1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞; division is only undefined for ±0/±0 and
>   ±∞/±∞.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured it out...

Kevin Goose said about different binary representation:

> I don't know the impact, but 0.0f and -0.0f don't have the same binary representation:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", BitConverter.GetBytes(0.0f)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", BitConverter.GetBytes(-0.0f)));

// Output
0, 0, 0, 0   
0, 0, 0, 128
```

I think I know that **impact**... Look at the output... It is Little-Endian. So greatest (most significant) 31st bit is set to 1. This bit is responsible for positive/negative flag inside number.
So when it is set to 1 the bit means "number is negative".

Why do we need it? I have analyzed all possible cases from Wikipedia article (thanks Sam) and finally I can say it is required only to get negative infinity as result... nothing else... all other is just consequence of this fact.

> > (1.0f / -0.0f)
>   -Infinity
>
> > (1.0f / +0.0f)
>   Infinity

Since negative bit allows us to get negative infinity in calculations I can say it is important to not lose negative bit during parsing XML. And it is reason of such code in XmlConvert.
Because float.Parse historically works very specific. It gives us always +0.0 and therefore positive infinity:

> > 1.0f / float.Parse("-0.0")
>   Infinity